# Can't name python file data_loading

Tags: python, pycharm

I created a Python file named data_loading in PyCharm and it showed up as a regular text file without the ability to run.

Then I switched the name to data_load and it worked.

I'm not sure why it couldn't run when it was named data_loading.

Is there a reason for this? I'm new to Python.

Proof here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZl9S.png

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherent in Python that prevents a script named **data_loading** from running. Either it's something in your environment that's preventing it from running, or the file was created differently in PyCharm for some reason. Either way, we don't have enough information to diagnose the issue with certainty.

I am certain that Python isn't the issue.